GD32 BootLoader
When I use the GD32 microcontroller which is same like stm32 for IAP upgrade operation, the APP program can only execute partial code after jumping to the APP program from BootLoader.The Flash partitions of each block are shown in the figure.

The BootLoader program and APP program are relatively simple, but when jumping to the APP program, only the code that displays the blue light is executed, and the subsequent code is not executed.
The bin compiled by the APP program is only 5k and will never exceed 26k.
int main(void) 
{
    // 初始化
    nvic_vector_table_set(0x08000000, 0x3000);
    systick_config();
    Usart_Init();
    systimer_init();
    Gpio_Init();
    DbgPrintf("START \n");
    
    Light_Display(BLUE);
    delay_1ms(2000);
//  for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
//  {
//      //DbgPrintf("test3\n");
//      delay_1ms(1000);
//      Light_Display(i);
//      DbgPrintf("Current i: %d\n", i);
//  }
    Light_Display(GREEN);
}

I have checked the compilation settings of the project and modified the code of the APP program, but it still freezes on a certain line

What is your IDE?If you are using keil I think you should configure correct address of vector table and application in the linker option also. See basic examples of stm32 IAP.
